# Simple error in my rails app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an error in my rails app telling me that the index method is undefined.
I have created a such simple form just for inserting data using the (new method page) only
but it is not working now for some reason

```
class PeoplesController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end

  def new
    @people = People.new
  end

  def create
    @people = People.new(params[:@people])
    if @people.save
      redirect_to new_people_path
    end
  end
end


# new.html.haml
<h2>Hello there!</h2>
<hr >
<%= form_for @people do |f| %>
    FirstName:<%= f.text_field :first %><br />
    LastName:<%= f.text_field :last %><br />
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the error code:

```
    NoMethodError in Peoples#new

Showing /Users/kasim/Desktop/form/app/views/peoples/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `people_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa33da58d58>:0x007fa34031c578>
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <h2>Hello there!</h2>
2: <hr >
3: <%= form_for @people do |f| %>
4:  FirstName:<%= f.text_field :first %><br />
5:  LastName:<%= f.text_field :last %><br />
6:  <%= f.submit %>
```

Comment: The new.html.erb code is below the controller code!

Comment: what's the exact error ?

Comment: The rails convention is to use singular names for models, e.g. `Person`.

Comment: pjam, I updated the code see the error message.

Comment: Mark, The model name is People but you looked at the controller name maybe.

Comment: `People` is not singular. `Person` is.

Comment: Yes right, But i have another app on my desktop and i used Person for it. so i'm trying to get used to the syntax. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: whether the columns first and last are there in table?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) says that a form_for call is equivalent to this

```
<%= form_for @post, :as => :post, :url => post_path(@post), :method => :put, :html => { :class => "edit_post", :id => "edit_post_45" } do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Notice that the url attribute is calling out to a named route.  In your case it appears the named route is people_index_path.  I'd run rake routes and make sure that the named route in question really exists.